# In Unity, my mesh is not rendering when huge (scale of 1400000)

Tags: unity

Any help/tips? This is for a space game and I really want realistic measures. The user WILL get really close to the sun. Any tips with dealing this? I can see the whole "Corona" but not the big sphere at the center

Comment: How are you rendering the Corona, and what's different about it compared to how you're rendering the central sphere? Where is your camera relative to the sphere and what are its near & far plane settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to scale something to 1.400.000, then you are doing something wrong.

If you want to create a massive planet to be ultra realistic and have everything on it loaded at all times, I doubt there is any machine capable at running something like that with more than 1 frame a second. And that's if I'm really optimistic.

The right way to do it, is to create the "illusion" that everything is there. You want to show a massive planet? Sure, instead of a sprite (or model) being millions of units away and millions of times scaled so that it covers half of the sky, make the planet be only 200-300 units away, so that it's closer, and scale it only 100 times, because it's already bigger. This would give the illusion that the planet is massive, and everyone knows planets are far away, so I doubt anyone will notice anything wrong with it.

You want to travel to the surface of the planet? Simple, while you approach the planet, for each unit that you travel, the planet moves half as much away from you, but becomes bigger 3 times as much (example numbers). This would make your player keep approaching the planet, and the planet will slowly get bigger, but it will look like you are just getting closer to it.

These are just examples of how you can approach problems like these. Floating points become less accurate the bigger they become, so it's always a bad idea if they are too big.

Comment: I only load the texture and the "sphere" mesh to watch the planet. But maybe you're right and I should just change and simulate movement everywhere. I have several problems loading stuff as big as that. Maybe time to rethking the base. Thanks!

Comment: @Dante It's not that you are doing something wrong when loading "stuff as big as that", it's that almost all games out there find tricks to make users think they have massive assets, while in reality having tiny assets and using tricks to make them look massive. When making a game, try to think how to make something look right to the user, rather than being "actually" right.

Comment: Ok. Will try to think of some math solution to change size according to distance while mantaining a static distance with the object.